# Java ftp upload and matching the file to website member

Tags: java, php, ftp, client, apache-commons

So I have a java webapp that lets the user upload a file to a server. I am using apache commons library FtpClient to do that.

I want to be able to match the uploaded file with the user of my website (the web app is only accessible from within the user area on the website). The website and whole user-interaction and management is in PHP / MySQL. So basically, I want to match the file uploaded in the Java webapp with the user in MySQL table who uploaded it.

How should I use PHP on the server to grab that file and match it with the user? Or maybe it's more convenient to do that from Java application somehow? Which approach do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a JSP by post with the file name that has been uploaded and the user name or the user id, This can be used to update or insert into a database where you can save the relation between the file and the user.

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It made me think that I could actually achieve the same with a PHP script (since I have never worked on JSP before). I can make Java app access the matchfile.php on the server that would perform a query on the database and update it. The only problem is that I don't know how to pass on the uploaded filename to the PHP file. It's created dynamically in the Java app. Anyone has an idea?